# Get all data from SQLITE in string format create one text file with this record save this file on device?

Tags: c#, xamarin

The following code is my database code ,it mention database name and table name .I want to create one text file with this record save this file on device on download folder. Add dummy data in local database more than 300 records .below my load data method this is post request inside a lab variable i have store my all URL response and this response i need to store on my text file

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection dataBase;
            protected async override void OnAppearing()
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
    
                var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
                var databasePath = Path.Combine(basePath, "SQLite.db3");
    
                dataBase = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);
                await dataBase.CreateTableAsync(typeof(LabTestData));
            }


 

public async void LoadData()
        {

            string myData = "{\"filter\": {\"labtestName\": [{\"labtestName\": \"Ada\"}]}}";
            var RestURL = "https:/LabTest/HSCLabTests";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(RestURL);

            StringContent content1 = new StringContent(myData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apptoken", "72f303a7-f1f0-45a0-ad2b-e6db29328b1a");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(RestURL, content1);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            UserData responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>(result);
            var lab = await dataBase.Table<LabTestData>().ToListAsync();

            if (lab.Count == 0)
            {
                await dataBase.InsertAllAsync(responseData.Results.LabTestData);
                LabTestData.ItemsSource = lab;
            }
            else
            {
                //Get The Data From Database                
                LabTestData.ItemsSource = lab;                
            }
            

        }
```

Comment: What does the LabTestData class look like?  You can write a ToString() method in the class to create a string which you can later savve to a file.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?  Looping through a list of data and writing it to a file is fairly trivial.

Comment: LabTestData.ItemsSource = lab;  

I need to store my "lab" variable data put into text file.so what I need to do?

Comment: @vivekpawar lab is list data? you want to store these list data into text file? you can convert list data to json, then save it into text file.